# String manipulation and File IO in C++?

Tags: c++, string, io

What I am trying to do is open a file containing a string, replace every character in that file with [character + 37], and output it on a different file "output.txt". What I'm guessing is a problem with the at function...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void encrypt(string text, int size) {
int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        text.at(i) = text.at(i) + 37;
    }
}

int main()
{
string string;
int length = string.length();

ifstream infile;
infile.open("input.txt");

if (infile.fail()) {
    cerr << "Error Opening File. " << endl;
    exit(1);
}

infile >> string;

infile.close();

encrypt(string, length);

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("output.txt");

if (infile.fail()) {
    cerr << "Error Opening File. " << endl;
    exit(1);
}

outfile << string;
outfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're working on a copy of your string, look up `by-value` and `by-reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should change your encrypt function `string` parameter to reference type:

```
void encrypt(string& text, int size) {
```

otherwise `string text` is a local variable in this function, and any changes will be lost after it ends.

Another thing is that you dont need `int size`, use `text.size()` instead. Also I see you are passing as size, result of this code:

```
string string;
int length = string.length();
```

here length will always be zero, also - as you can see your variable name is the same as the type std::string, why you use such name? This is one of the reason you should not use `using namespace std;`

Third thing, after :

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("output.txt");
```

you check if it is in fail state by using `infile` instead of `outfile`

```
if (infile.fail()) {
```

better change this check to `if (!infile) {`

Answer (score 0):

As said by @marcinj, your `encrypt` routine only modifies a copy of original string, and the copy is lost when function exists.

But anyway, what you do is rather dangerous: your encrypt function can take printable characters and transform then into non printable ones while you use the text interface of streams. Even if it works, the file might not contain a correct string when done.

For example the character `ù` (which is common in french) will become a space which is the string delimiter, and even worse, the `õ` (common in portuguese) will become a `\n` not speaking of the `Û` that will give a null character!